# After change the UIScrollView's frame with animation, the scrollView can't scroll on the horizontal direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

I want to hide or show the `UIScrollView` on the screen, so I just change its frame.

But when it displays, I find I can't scroll it in the horizontal direction. To scroll it in the horizontal direction I must scroll it in the vertical direction, then I can scroll it in the horizontal direction.
The frame setting is ok, and the contentSize is ok too.

I reset ScrollView's frame and contentSize, I even bring it to the front because there are some other views. Change frame to show is not just to show, another view will change its frame to hide.

A more detailed, can't scroll to right, left is ok.

Comment: If you just need to hide the scroll view, you can use scrollView.hidden = YES

Comment: Either use Arun's suggestion or if you want to do it your way after all, always apply appropriate contentSize to ScrollView when you play with its frame. Make sure the content size's width is greater than your view's width. If it is less or equal, it won't scroll horizantally.

Comment: try  this  ScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width+required space to scroll, height);

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to hide the scroll view, you can use `scrollView.hidden = YES`

Answer (score 0):

set scrollview content size width to zero

```
ScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(0, height);
```